# Why does the php script (Gmail API, moometric/GSuiteSignatureManager) update the email signature of only 100 users?

Tags: php, gmail-api

I am trying to update all users in gsuite email signatures using php scripts [moometric/GSuiteSignatureManager](https://github.com/moometric/GSuiteSignatureManager/blob/master/README.md). The script updates the signature of 100 users and stops. There are no errors, it just stops. What is the limit of 100 users?

Comment: https://github.com/moometric/GSuiteSignatureManager/issues/2

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thank you! I change the code on line 83 in file `signature/src/mooSignature.php` with this (500 is maximum allowed)
`$output = $this->googleServiceDirectory->users->listUsers(Array('domain' => "$this->domain", "projection" => "full", "maxResults" => 500));`